# How cut specifics number from string and operate on them in select mysql

Tags: mysql, select, char, numbers

I have data in a field that looks like this:

```
SR01-20, MA-5
```

I want to separate the numbers that are always after the '-' sign and sum them up. Somehow select them, convert to numbers and add.

The result of this example should be:

```
25
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
select substring_index(substring_index(col,',',1),'-',-1) +  
    substring_index(substring_index(col,',',2),'-',-1) as result
from table_name;
```

And, you can add `+0` to convert `substring_index` 's result to numeric.

***UPDATE :***

First, you have to split `col` by `","` as delimiter. then `SUM()` the value with `GROUP BY`. 
You can try this sql query :

```
SELECT id,sum(substring_index(spl,'-',-1)) sa from
(
    SELECT id,SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(e.col, ',', n.n), ',', -1) spl
        FROM table_name e CROSS JOIN 
    (
         SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
             FROM 
            (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
         ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
            ORDER BY n
    ) n
     WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(e.col) - LENGTH(REPLACE(e.col, ',', '')))
     ORDER BY id, col
) t
group by id
```

I don't know your table structure, but i hope you understand what i mean in that query.

Comment: This works perfectly for this example, which is great! But what if the number of ',' in my strings varies? In the same column I have the following:  `SR01-20,M-5` as well as `SR-15` and `SR2-14,M-5,ZR-4` ...

Comment: @BasPawelczak It will be achieve with alot of code.

Comment: It works! Perfectly! I'm still figuring out how to implement it, but this is great. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `substring_index()` and conversion:

```
select sum(substring_index(col, '-', -1) + 0)
```

The `+ 0` does silent conversion.  So if the part after the hyphen is not a number, then it will be converted to zero and no error is issued.

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d41d8) is a SQL Fiddle showing the results.

Comment: This return `60 for SR01-20` AND `15 FOR MA-5`. I think `-1` should use `length function`.

Comment: For me this returns the last numer (here 5) from SR01-20, MA-5

Comment: @BasPawelczak Did you mean 'SR01-20, MA-5' from one field and one row? Not from one field and two rows?

Comment: Yes. One field and one row.